# What do I do with preparation nominations?

Tags: elite-dangerous

At the start of every new Powerplay cycle, I am given a handful of preparation nominations to use. What are these for? What should I be nominating?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the name implies, they're nomination votes that help rank the top-ten systems in the Preparation list. Essentially this works out to them being effort-free way of completing a preparation activity, and allows for a sort of bootstraping of the nomination system order in each new cycle.

To use your votes, you select a system in the Preparation list in the Power overview, and then use the Pledge to Nominate button.

[image: nomination button on overview]

This will bring up a dialog which allows you to select how many nomination votes to use:

[image: vote selection dialog]

Each vote causes the current preparation value of the system to increase by one without you having to actually complete the normal preparation task.

Comment: sounds pretty useless... you can only nominate what is already in the top 10?

Comment: It seems so. I *thought* you could nominate any system at least by visiting it and using the Power Contact, but after checking this doesn't appear to be the case.